# DotNetOpenAuth custom nonce

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I am using the `DotNetOpenAuth` `WebConsumer` object to make token requests to an OAuth 1.0a Service Provider. I was wondering whether it is possible to use a custom nonce when sending requests to the service and, if so, how I configure the consumer to use the custom nonce generator.

Comment: If you add to your question any details about why you want to customize the nonce, our answers may be able to include some workaround or alternate way to reach your goal.

Comment: @Andrew I have no real need to use a custom nonce presently, however I was wondering if it was possible to set a custom nonce generator similarly to a custom token generator. Your reply has answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there's an extensibility point for customizing the nonce for OAuth 1.0 consumers.